# I keep getting an invalid syntax but i CAN not find it

Tags: python

```
if (x == True):
     if (beverage_bought == True):
        if (fries_bought == True):
            print("You bought: " + x + " x, " + beverage + " drink, " + fries + " fries, and " + 
ketchup_string + " ketchup packets.")
            total = total - 1
        else:
            print ("You bought: " + x, " x, " + beverage + " drink, no fries and " + ketchup_string + " ketchup packets.")
        elif (fries_bought == True):
            print ("You bought: " + x + " x, nothing to drink, " + fries + " fries, and " + ketchup_string + " ketchup packets.")
        else:
            print ("You bought: " + x, " x, nothing to drink, no fries, and " + ketchup_string + " 
ketchup packets.")

print (total)
```

it keeps saying I have an invalid syntax for the line with elif

Comment: `print("you bought:',x,"x"...)` should be used. Or you can use `.format()` or fstrings.

Comment: You cannot have an `elif` condition after you already used an `else`

Comment: You cannot set an `elif` after the `else` which holds every other cases

Comment: The elif is bad indented, it should be like the second if and the last else

Comment: Concerning code style: `if (x == True):` should be written as `if x == True:` or just `if x:`. The same applies to the other comparisons.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `elseif` after `else`. `else` must be the last of the chain: `if` > `elif` > `elif` > `else`.

You should remove indents of the second `elif` to align it with the first `if`.

```py
if x:
    if beverage_bought:
        if fries_bought:
            print("You bought: " + x + " x, " + beverage + " drink, " + fries + " fries, and " + ketchup_string + " ketchup packets.")
            total = total - 1
        else:
            print("You bought: " + x, " x, " + beverage + " drink, no fries and " + ketchup_string + " ketchup packets.")

    elif fries_bought:
        print("You bought: " + x + " x, nothing to drink, " + fries + " fries, and " + ketchup_string + " ketchup packets.")
    else:
        print("You bought: " + x, " x, nothing to drink, no fries, and " + ketchup_string + " ketchup packets.")

print(total)
```

Comment: If this answer solved the problem you cna mark it as the solution so that the question is marked as resolved.